# Archived Meteor Documentation

Tags: meteor

Does anyone know where to find MeteorJS documentation for past versions?  There does not seem to be an option on the website to switch to an older version like there is on other documentation sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the tag for the version you want and run the app in the /docs directory.
The docs directory is a meteor app. All you need to do is `meteor` inside of it.

E.g for version 0.7.2:

```
git clone git@github.com:meteor/meteor.git
cd meteor
git checkout release/0.7.2
cd docs
meteor
open localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to dig in through the GitHub repo history for MeteorJS https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commits/devel/docs

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to revive this thread a year in. But for users of the current Meteor 1.3 release it might be reassuring to know that you can get at least access to the Meteor 1.2 guide directly on guide.meteor.com via the small drop-down menu on top. Just switch it from "1.3" to "1.2".

For getting the full API docs or even older versions of the guide the currently accepted answer still applies, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can read it in plain text (with no sourcecode examples) at:

- [src meteor docs 0.6.5](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/0.6.5/docs/client/api.html)
- [src meteor docs 0.7.2](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/0.7.2/docs/client/api.html)