# Where can I find Meteor 1.2 documentation

Tags: meteor

The announcement of Meteor 1.3 sounds great, but we're in the middle of a development push and need to make the move to 1.3 on our schedule, not Meteor's. So I want to reference the Meteor 1.2 documentation to match the Meteor infrastructure that we are currently using.

Meteor.com is now showing the 1.3 documentation, so my question is: where can I find the older documentation. Moving our infrastructure is already destabling. Having to work with new documentation and an old runtime is even worse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871093/archived-meteor-documentation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and got this answer in the meteor forum (https://forums.meteor.com/t/where-is-meteor-1-2-documentation/20698):

> Just to add - if you're referring to the 1.2 docs that were hosted at http://docs.meteor.com, for now you have to grab them from a meteor source checkout.

```
git clone https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git
cd meteor; git checkout release/METEOR@1.2.1
cd docs
meteor
Access 1.2.1 docs at the usual http://localhost:3000
```